# C# covariance on generic methods

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

In Java I can easily write:

```java
interface A { void foo(); }
class B implements A { public void foo() {} }
class C implements A { public void foo() {} }

<T> List<T> combined(Collection<? extends T> a, Collection<? extends T> b) {
    List<T> res = new ArrayList<>();
    res.addAll(a);
    res.addAll(b);
    return res;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<A> list = combine(Arrays.asList(new B()), Arrays.asList(new C()));
}
```

The above code compiles when put inside a class (ignoring modifiers etc).

The goal is to write a function `Combine` which takes two `IEnumerable`s of *potentially different* types A and B which both inherit from some T. The compiler *should infer the type of T* and return an `IEnumerable<T>` without me having to explicitly specify any type in the function call.

How would I do this in C#?

Comment: Use the `out` modifier: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier

Comment: @UnholySheep `out` does not work on methods, only on types. Hence my confusion.

Comment: @Dracam This case cannot be automatically resolved by the compiler. If `B` and `C` both implement 2 interfaces (say `A1` and `A2`) what should be the return type of this method, `IEnumerable<A1>`, `IEnumerable<A2>`...? Also, if `B` and `C` inherit from a base class `A` that itself inherits from `A0`, should the return type be `IEnumerable<A>`, `IEnumerable<A0>`...?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same thing in c#, see below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var lst1 = new List<A>();
        var lst2 = new List<B>();
        var result = Merge<ICommon>(lst1, lst2);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Merge<T>(IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<T> b){
        foreach(var itm in a)
            yield return itm;
        foreach(var itm in b)
            yield return itm;
    }
}

public interface ICommon {}
public class A : ICommon{}
public class B : ICommon{}
```

---

> The compiler should infer the type of T and return an `IEnumerable<T>` without me having to explicitly specify any type in the function call.

That is not possible, you will have to specify the common type for `T`.

Comment: Do you know if infering T might be possible in a future release?

Comment: @Dracam - I doubt it would. Think also of multiple interface implementations where multiple common interfaces could exist, the compiler would have to guess which one was intended.

Comment: @vc74 You are correct. Igor is doing exactly that in his example, but my much-desired type inference does not work

Comment: @Igor Some type systems like the ones from Java and Scala make the inference work, at least with base classes (not interfaces). I wonder if this has to do with type erasure ..

Comment: @Dracam - Your best bet would be to see if `@EricLippert` can take a look at the question. I believe he implemented/designed Covariance in .net so he could tell you if this was something that would be considered in a future release or how it compares to Java exactly.

Answer (score 1):

No, the compiler's type inference algorithm will not go up the hills looking for a common base type, and its not something that only applies to generic type parameters. This wont work either:

```
IFoo foo = condition ? b : c;
```

Why? Well, because its not always clear what the base type should be and it can be a source of bugs. How does the compiler know where to stop? After all, everything can be reduced to the common type `object`.

Also, should user defined conversions be taken into account? And should common base types after every posible conversión be considered? It can go on forever. Its simply much better if you explicitly state what type you want, and not have the compiler guessing what your intention was.

The rule is that the type inference algorithm will only use as applicable candidates the types that are explicitly used in the expression. If no valid type is found among these candidates then the inference will simply fail.

In the previous example, the solution is of course:

```
IFoo foo = condition ? (IFoo)b : c;
```

And in your case, the solution is not relying on the inference algorithm, you need to explicitly declare the desired generic type parameter.

Following up comments, the way C# handles this solves unintended breaking changes:

```
class A: IFoo
class B: IFoo, IBar
```

A consumer writes some code:

```
var foo = someCondition ? a : b //asume this is legal and resolves type to IFoo
```

Now, someone thinks its time to update `A` to `A: IFoo, IBar` and suddenly the consumer breaks.

Comment: I see your point with conversions and why they are tricky, but what is wrong with finding the common base type up the hierarchy? When I try to combine two lists of unrelated types I would of course expect an IEnumerable<object>

Comment: @Dracam that might also be an error where you expect some other type inferred and the code compiles assuming you want `object`. Also, the amount of ambigous errors would be huge; what happens if two conversions are applicable? Should reference conversions come before user defined conversions? Should one user defined conversion precede two reference conversiones? etc. etc. The whole things turns into a mess that is hard to understand and predict. C#'s way is much much easier to understand.

Comment: @Dracam Also C#'s way of handling things avoids unintended breaking changes. See update.

Comment: @InBetween some valid points, thank you. I guess I'll just have to get used to the careful C# way of doing things

Answer (score 0):

It works if you don't rely on type inference and fully specify all types on the function:

```
class CommonInterfaces
{
    public static void DoWork()
    {
        var lst1 = new List<A>();
        var lst2 = new List<B>();
        var result = Merge<ICommon, A, B>(lst1, lst2);

    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Merge<T, TA, TB>(IEnumerable<TA> a, IEnumerable<TB> b) where TA: T where TB: T
    {
        foreach (var itm in a)
            yield return itm;
        foreach (var itm in b)
            yield return itm;
    }
}

public interface ICommon { }
public class A : ICommon { }
public class B : ICommon { }
```

Thanks to @Igor for most of the typing on this